# Gameobject is moving even though I only rotated it

Tags: unity, c#

Ok, this problem is kinda hard to explain, but I have this mouselook script as follows:

```
yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

playerHead.gameObject.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yaw, -pitch);
```

(The place I got this script from had pitch in the x axis, but for some reason up and down is the z axis of this game object, and it didn't work right unless I inverted it)

So as I understand it this should only change the rotation, not actually move the gameobject. (too be clear here the camera is inside a game object called playerHead, which is what I want to move to move the camera and the first person arms). So I test this, and looking forwards, as the game starts off, the position and rotation are all 0, depicted below.

For context in the image playerhead is selected so it's the object with the axis near the front of the plane.
[image: Looking forwards]

Everything's fine right?

But then I turn around, and playerhead has moved. Not only has it moved despite localRotation, as I understand it, being something that should only effect rotation, but according to the inspector it's position is still 0, 0, 0.

For context in the image below playerhead is is selected so it's the object with the axis near the back of the plane.
[image: Looking backwards]

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain why playerhead moved, and how I could only change it's position, not it's rotation.

Comment: I notice your transform gizmos are set to "center" mode (drop-down in the top left, with a grey box with a diagonal line through it, and a red circle in the center). Try changing this to "pivot" mode. You might find the pivot of the object is somewhere other than the center of the camera.

Comment: @DMGregory ah, that does show the pivot is in the center of the plane, so if it's rotating about that it that would explain why it's moving - how would I move the pivot?

Comment: Drag the transform gizmo until the pivot point is where you want it to be, then select the camera child and move it to (0, 0, 0) in its parent's coordinates, so it's sitting at the position of the pivot. Post your solution with relevant screenshots as an Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to DMGregory who put the solution in the comments. The trouble was with the game object's pivot point. As pictured below the gameobject doesn't change position when I rotate it any more.
[image: fixed rotation]

Comment: This answer would be more useful to future readers if it explained how to spot the pivot problem and the steps you took to fix it, rather than just the successful result.